# Enable textbox with VBA Office 2011 Mac

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

I'm using Office 2011 for Mac and I'm trying to create a macro for a Word document that simply unlock an inserted TextBox.

The standard procedure that I used on Word for Windows is: `ThisDocument.<TextBoxName>.Locked=False`, but this fails saying that there is no object with that name.

Any clue about this?

Comment: Are you running the code from the same document? Also have you checked there are no references missing? You should post your whole code as it might be something else causing the issue.

Comment: yes from the same document. The code is really really simple, I've a textbox inside the document and in the sub AutoOpen() I have ThisDocument.TextBox1.Locked = False.

Comment: Okay, stupid question time - have you checked that the **code** name of the textbox _is_ actually `Textbox1` ?

Comment: well that's a legit question, I think yes since I have the method TextBox1_Change() inside the macro. I can't confirm this at 100% because as now I can't figure out how to show properties of a TextBox in office for Mac ( usually that was right-click->properties in dev mode but seems not here... )

Comment: It can be that since I've created these TextBoxes as ActiveX object they aren't correctly rendered by office for Mac?

Comment: Yes - Mac doesn't support ActiveX, unless you have a specific reason for ActiveX you should always stick to standard form controls

Comment: Mistery solved. Noob me. Thank you very much for support.

Comment: @Poldou You should probably consider posting an answer to your question. However, it has been already answered in other threads.